# Anylogic - delay dependent on resources

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create a service that varies depending on the resources that are used.

For example if a nurse were to carry out the service it could take 10 - 35 mins, whereas if this is carried out by another member of staff it could take 5-25 minutes.

I have had a go - as in the picture below, however, what I've written doesn't seem to be working.

Resource dependent delays

[image: [1]]

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since the parameter "Delay time" accepts a value, you need to replace if-else statement with [**conditional expression "? :"**](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/code/Conditional.html). The syntax is the following: **condition** ? **value if true** : **value if false**. 
Moreover, your should use another condition to check if the agent has a resource unit from "Nurse":

```
agent.resourceUnitOfPool(Nurse) != null ? triangular(10, 15, 35) :
triangular(5, 10, 25)
```